# Alter the chart data name "Slice 1"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a query and from there I am using a SQL code in order to select the column FaultName and calculate the repetition of Faults using Count(*). I am grouping by FaultName.

However, some of the FaultNames are normally left empty and as the consequence on my chart there is a FaultName always left without a name or with name specified as "Slice 1". Wondering if anyone can help me to automatically change the FaultName to "Unknown" every time the chart appears.

```
SQL= "SELECT Query.[FaultName], Count(*) As [Count] FROM Query GROUP BY Query.[Fault Name];"
```

My Query is:

> FaultName    -         Count(*)
>
> A              ----------------       10
>
> B              ----------------       2
>
> -------------------5

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
"SELECT Nz(Query.FaultName,"Unknown") AS NzFaultName, Count(*) AS [Count] FROM Query GROUP BY Query.FaultName;"
```